# How to pass an array from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send some data from jsp to servlet using ajax call; In my java script I have the following method:

```
function sendMessage(){
        var cellPhones=[];
        var title=$('#subject').val();
        var text=$('#smsText').val();
        var groupsName=$('#dg').datagrid('getSelections');
        for(var i=0;i<groupsName.length;i++){
            cellPhones.push(groupsName[i].cellphone);
        }
        alert(cellPhones);

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<%=basePath%>/SendMsgServlet?flag=sendSms",
            data:{
                title:title,
                text:text,
                cellPhones:cellPhones
            }
        }).done(function(){
            alert("ok");
        })
    }
```

and in my doPost method I have:

```
if("sendSms".equals(flag.trim())){
        String title=request.getParameter("title");
        String text=request.getParameter("text");
        String[] cellPhones=request.getParameterValues("cellPhones");

        this.sendSms(title,text,cellPhones,request,response);
    }
```

The problem is that the cellPhones is null, nut the alert is not null, Could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a class, which will have array as an attribute. set the field value and then set the obj to request. This will not only help you in the servlet but can also be used incase you want to send some data back to your jsp.

Answer (score 0):

At ajax you are sending values as array like:

```
 url= "cellPhone[]=121212&cellPhone[]=121212&cellPhone[]=121212"
```

But, at servlet you are trying to get value as single value. You need to get values as array `[]`. Try,

```
String[] cellPhones=request.getParameterValues("cellPhones[]");
                                                          |- Use array sign
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, All I had to do was to convert cellphones to string,no need to hidden element I just added this line of code:

```
var cellPhone=cellPhones.toString();
```